# Android AccessibilityService: How to record and replay view clicks?

Tags: android, accessibility

I am trying to implement an AccessibilityService that records the user's actions (only click events at this point) and stores them, such that they can be replayed at a later point in time.

For this I register for `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED` events and check if I could somehow recover them later on (when all I have is a reference to the window / root node of the activity) by using two strategies:

1. Get the clicked view's id and look for this id in the root node's tree
2. Get the clicked view's text and look for this text in the root node's tree

I have tested this in various applications and different parts of the Android system and the results have been very confusing. About half of the views were not recoverable by any of the two strategies, and some views were sometimes reported as being recoverable and sometimes not. I found out that the latter was due to a race condition, since the accessibility service runs in a different process than the application to which the clicked views belong.

My question now is whether there is a better way to get a handle to a view in an accessibility and find this view again in a later execution of the application.

Below you find the code of my AccessiblityService class:

```
public class RecorderService extends AccessibilityService {

    private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
            AccessibilityNodeInfo node = event.getSource();

            if (node == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "node is null");
                return;
            }

            AccessibilityNodeInfo root = getRootInActiveWindow();
            if (root == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "root is null");
                return;
            }

            // Strategy #1: locate node via its id
            String id = node.getViewIdResourceName();
            if (id == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "id is null");
            } else {

                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> rootNodes = root.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId(id);
                if (rootNodes.size() == 1) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "success (via id)");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "multiple nodes with that id");
                }
            }

            // Strategy #2: locate node via its text
            CharSequence text = node.getText();
            if (text == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "text is null");
            } else {
                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> rootNodes = root.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(text.toString());
                if (rootNodes.size() == 1) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "success (via text)");
                    return;
                }
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "failed, node was not recoverable");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i("Key", event.getKeyCode() + "");

        return true;
        // return super.onKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }
}
```

I am developing this on SDK Version 21 (Lollipop) and testing it on a HTC Nexus M8 and a Samsung Galaxy Note2, both showing similar results.

Comment: Yeah, that's about as good as you can do. You could also try using ancestor view IDs and child index as unique identifiers, though that won't help much for something like a ListView (though there you could rely on the CollectionItemInfo).

Comment: I tried using getParent() on the source node combined with getChild(...) to check if the child node would be recoverable through the parent, but the latter often returned null and I do not understand why.